# I gets an error when I calculate time intervals using diff(periods=1) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that records times of events that occur from today's 08:00 AM to tomorrow's 07:00 AM, each day(Therefore, I don't want to add date values, to save the storage and to simply matintain it). So, it looks like this:

```
>>> df.Time[63010:]
63010    23:59:59.431256    # HH:MM:SS.ffffff
63011    23:59:59.431256
63012    23:59:59.431256
63013    23:59:59.431256
63014    23:59:59.431256
63015    23:59:59.618764
63016    23:59:59.821756
63017    23:59:59.821756
63018    23:59:59.821756
63019    23:59:59.821756
63020    00:00:00.025058    # date changes here
63021    00:00:00.025058
63022    00:00:00.025058
63023    00:00:00.228202
63024    00:00:00.228202
63025    00:00:00.228202
63026    00:00:00.228202
.....
```

I want to make a new dataframe that records time intervals between each event, so I tried:

```
>>> TimeDiff = df.Time.diff(periods=1)
```

But it gets a value that I don't intend to get, which is:

```
63018                    00:00:00
63019                    00:00:00
63020    -1 days +00:00:00.203302    <-- -1 days?
63021                    00:00:00
63022                    00:00:00
```

I know that it happens because I don't have date values. How can I fix this problem without adding dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that your error is due to missing date values then you should try pandas build in function `to_datetime`:

Example: `df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])`

you can also adjust the format of the date by adding a format argument like so:

Example: `df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], format="%m/%d/%Y)`